# How to set the MAX limit to a int?

Tags: c++

How to set the limit for the limit :  (1≤n≤10^16)

for example

```
const int MAX_N = 1e16;
```

I am getting this error :

```
overflow in conversion from 'double' to 'int' changes value from '1.0e+16' to '2147483647'
```

Comment: `int` on your system just can't represent that value; it's too big.  You can choose a smaller value, or use a different type; `long long int` or `int64_t` should be big enough.

Comment: In addition to being of a wrong type, `10,000,000,000,000,000` is outside `int` limit on most computers. You should use a 64-bit type, e.g. `int64_t`.

Comment: Use `const long long MAX_N = 10000LL * 10000 * 10000 * 10000;`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The advice is good. It is good because simply converting 1E16 to an integer may result in a one-off value: Numbers above 2^53, ca. 9E15, do not necessarily have exact representations in an IEEE-754 double any longer. I suppose that can make even a simple-looking literal like 1E16 inexact. Of course a compiler could infer intent here but I'm not sure it's allowed to do that.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Note: comment updated.  IAC, best to use integer constants for integers.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Comment updated, too ;-). Well, as demonstrated a concise notation may be less error-prone ;-).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica One alternative might be to use `const auto MAX_N = 1'0'0'00'000'0000'00000`. Use `auto` to automatically deduce the minimum type needed, and use digit separator `'`, instead of using `*`, which could potentially overflow.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Interesting, yet `10000LL * ...` will only overflow `long long` types.

Comment: Note that there is a header <climits> or <limits.h> that defines a macro INT_MAX, the max value of int.

Answer (score 1):

Id you want to set a data type to its maxor min limit value, then you can use `std::numeric_limits`. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) about that.

And for having the maximum value for an `int`, you would write something like

```
int v = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```